# Using if condition with assume

Tags: matlab, if-statement

I got the following error while I am using if condition with assume, so please any help:
Too many output arguments with if condition, and assume

```
clear all; 
close all;
clc;
syms x y;
yin=[(solve(-1500<.2500*x+.7500*y+20.78,y)), 
(solve(.2500*x+.7500*y+20.78<1500,y))]
 % %@x=100
 yin2=[-100/3 - 152003/75, 147847/75 - 100/3]

 if assume(-2060<y & y<1938)
display('ok')
else
 display('nothing')
end
```

I expect the output should be possible answers of the interval I added

Comment: Well, `assume` does not return a boolean so the error makes sense. Perhaps you want to use `assumptions` and check its size?

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply.
I do understand your point of view, but how could I do what I want?, Is there any suggestions from you, 

Hope you could help!

Comment: What exactly is it that you would like to check?

Comment: Thanks again, 
For this interval -2060<y <1938
All I want is to check if y is greater than left hand side which is in this case (-2060), and smaller than right hand side which is in this case (1938), 
Did you get me ?
Looking to hearing from you soon as I am new to Matlab,

Comment: [`isAlways`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/isalways.html) maybe?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you want to use `assume()` here. A simple conditional will compare variables with values:

```matlab
if -2060<y && y<1938
    display('ok')
else
    display('nothing')
end
```

Either `&` or `&&` would work. The short circuit `&&` will skip the second check if the first fails.